# What does the ## operator mean/do in this C macro?

Tags: c, function, macros

```
#define swap(t, x, y) \
  do { \
   t safe ## x ## y; \
   safe ## x ## y = x; \
   x = y; \
   y = safe ## x ## y; \
  } while (0)
```

The code swaps arguments x and y of type t.

Comment: what output you got ?

Comment: The double pound sign ## is used for token concatenation. Google for the same

Comment: To keep following unwritten (?) rules about C macros, I suggest you name your macros in ALL CAPS ... `#define SWAP(t, x, y)`

Answer (score 3):

The ## (double number sign) operator concatenates two tokens in a macro invocation (text and/or arguments) given in a macro definition.
**[Read More](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc09numnum.htm)**

Answer (score 2):

The double pound sign `##` is used for token concatenation.

This is how your code would look without pound key for simplicity.

```
#define swap(t, x, y) \
  do { \
   t safexy; \
   safexy = x; \
   x = y; \
   y = safexy; \
  } while (0)
```

You need to abide by the following rules when using `##`

- The `##` operator cannot be the very first or very last item in the
  replacement list of a macro definition.
- The last token of the item in front of the `##` operator is
  concatenated with first token of the item following the `##`
  operator.
- Concatenation takes place before any macros in arguments are
  expanded. If the result of a concatenation is a valid macro
  name, it is available for further replacement even if it appears
  in a context in which it would not normally be available.
- If more than one `##` operator and/or `#` operator appears in the
  replacement list of a macro definition, the order of evaluation of 
  the operators is not defined.

For more understanding [read here](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc09numnum.htm).

Answer (score 2):

When you invoke this macro, for example like this:

```
swap(double, a, b);
```

it gets replaced by inline code to swap the two values, namely:

```
do {
   double safeab;
   safeab = a;
   a = b;
   b = safeab;
} while (0);
```

Things to note:

- The swap requires a temporary variable. In order to create this variable, the type must be known. (Some compilers allow you to use `typeof(a)`, but that's not standard and thus not portable.)
- The name of the temporary variable is made up of the names of the variables to be swapped by means of the preprocessor's concatenation operator `##`. This operator is available only in macro bodies and creates a new token by pasting the adjacent tokens together. Note that the name creation fails if one of the swapping operands are compound, e.g. `a[i]` or `p->x`. The name creation by concatenation is a bit overcareful. Because the swapping takes place in its own scope, it is safe to shadow variables, except those being swapped of course. Just pick a name outside your regular naming conventions and cross your fingers.
- The `do { ... } while (0)` wrapper is a common method to make the macro behave like a function, which is important if they are used as the only expression of an `if` or `while` body.
- The backslashes at the end allow you to spread a macro over various lines. It is customary to line them up nicely at the end, so that they don't clutter the code.

Given that the macro doesn't work for compound expressions, you don't buy much with it. It also isn't type generic, because when you invoke the macro, the type must be known. Write a small static function for swapping; that's clearer in my opinion.

The [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/cpp/swapmacro.html) has a question and strong opinions about type-generic swap macros, too.

Comment: Since you can't swap compound expressions anyway, I'm not sure that the 'Given' clause is really applicable.  You can only swap … hmm, l-values, I suppose.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, you can swap, say, `a[i]` and `a[j]` or `p->x`and `p->y`, can't you? That won't concatenate to a valid variable name and isn't a "simple" one-token expression. Maybe "compound expression" isn't a good word; I've used "compound" here as it is used in "compound literal", namely to refer to compound data types.

Comment: By the way, I'm also not sure that the question is exclusively about the `##` operator, as everyone here seems to assume. The original, admittedly rather vague question title was "How does this code work?".

Comment: Fair point on expressions such as subscripted array elements; the elaborate temporary variable name gets wrecked.  I don't really see there was anything else (out her than the `##`) to confuse the OP.

Comment: @M Oehm The do { ... } while (0) wrapper is a common method to make the macro behave like a function, which is important if they are used as the only expression of an if or while body. - I couldn’t understand this point. Can you please explain why it is important to use the wrapper if used as the only expression?

Comment: @Shyam: The macro looks like a function, so it will be used like a function in code. But it expands to more than one statement. if you have `if (x) MACRO(a);` and it expand to `if (x) first(a); second(a);` you get a surprise: `second(a)` will be called unconditionally. The wrapper prevents this.

Comment: Got it! Thanks much @M Oehm